# how to write and run a shell program on terminal without saving it first

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a Linux server, I have access to a directory but I am not allowed to write anything to that directory. I can run commands from system prompt. Now I have to find values of specific field of some files in that dir and do some comparisons. I have a script on a test server can do that. But I can't install my script to the server, I am asking if there is anyway I type a specific command, then I can write and run a shell program without saving the program? Thank you!

Comment: Can you write to another directory, like `/tmp`?

Comment: You can type the script at the command prompts.  You might type a `(` on a line on its own first, then the script, then `)` on another new line, to run it all in a sub-shell, and to run none of it until you've entered it all.  Your typing could be 'pasting'.  But I'd save the command in a script in `/tmp` as already suggested, and then run it from there.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan, the way you to run it in asub-shell using () works!

Comment: There's a potential problem with the paste-it-in approach: if your script contains tab characters (e.g. for indentation), the shell may interpret them as filename autocompletion and ... get confused. Removing tabs first will solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the script on another host, you can run it this way:

```
wget http://your.host.net/script -O- | sh -s
```

If the host is not accessible via HTTP, you can use any other protocol you want.

Also you can write a script direct in a shell:

```
sh -s <<EOF
echo Hello
echo I am script
echo Nice to meet you
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use backtics to execute the result of another command.

```
`wget /path/to/your/script/stored/remotely -O-`
```

(you might use `sftp` to fetch the script instead)

Another option is to write a program that uses a tty to control an `ssh` session, then the script is stored on the ssh client but the commands run on the server.  Perhaps the `expect` tool would help with that.

Comment: Thank you, I will try towrite another program that uses a tty to control an ssh session. I don't have expect tool in my linux.